# Python: Return index of an element of an array given specific conditions

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, element

Thanks for checking this out for me. New to python. 
So, I have an array,    time=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....] and I need the index of the first element where time > 7. 
What I have so far:
time.index( np.where( time > 7))
getting error:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index' 
This was s hot in the dark so far.
help please!
Thanks!

Comment: Please show some code.  This will get you a stronger and quicker answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use numpy, you can do as follows:

```
time_l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

import numpy as np
a = np.array(time_l)
print(np.where(a > 7))
# Prints (array([7]),)
```

Dont need to use index on your list with numpy.

You can also use list comprehension:

```
print([i for i,v in enumerate(time_l) if v > 7])
# gives: [7]
```

Alternative way, with generator:

```
time_l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(next(i for i,v in enumerate(time_l) if v > 7))
# prints 7
```

And more intuitive way, using for loop and index:

```
for v in time_l:
    if v > 7:
        print(time_l.index(v))
        break
```